# unable to redisplay changed headerView text in UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I haven't been able to figure out how to redisplay my changed text in my headerView in my UITableViewController.  I do a "removeFromSuperview", and it does get removed, but then it doesn't redisplay the new headerView after I re-add it to my subView.  Here is my code:

```
    - (UIView *)headerView
    {
    if (headerView){
        [headerView removeFromSuperview];
        [headerView release];
    }
    UIButton *headerLabel = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    if (displayOnly == NO)
        [headerLabel setTitle:@"Click here to switch to display only mode." forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    else
        [headerLabel setTitle:@"Click here to switch to practice session mode." forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    float w = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
    CGRect headerLabelFrame = CGRectMake(8.0, 8.0, w - 16.0, 30.0);
    [headerLabel setFrame:headerLabelFrame];
    CGRect headerViewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, w, 48);
    [headerLabel addTarget:self action:@selector(switch) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:headerViewFrame];
    [headerView addSubview:headerLabel];
    return headerView;
}
- (void) switch
{
    if (displayOnly == YES)
    {
        displayOnly = NO;
        [self headerView];
    }  
    else
    {
        displayOnly = YES;
        [self headerView]; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried to call `[headerView setNeedsDisplay];` after setting new title to label instead of recreating the view every time? 
And may be you even don't need to do it at all. If you store `UIButton` and `UIView`, if I'm right it will redraw itself automatically when you put new title to it. Something like so:

in your .h file

```
UIButton* headerLabel;
UIView*   headerView;
```

and in your .m file

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self headerView]; 
}

- (UIView *)headerView{
    if(headerView){
        return headerView;
    }
    if(!headerLabel){
        headerLabel = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    }
    if (displayOnly == NO)
        [headerLabel setTitle:@"Click here to switch to display only mode." forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    else
        [headerLabel setTitle:@"Click here to switch to practice session mode." forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    float w = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
    CGRect headerLabelFrame = CGRectMake(8.0, 8.0, w - 16.0, 30.0);
    [headerLabel setFrame:headerLabelFrame];
    CGRect headerViewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, w, 48);
    [headerLabel addTarget:self action:@selector(switch) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:headerViewFrame];
    [headerView addSubview:headerLabel];
    return headerView;
}

- (void) switch{
    if (displayOnly == YES){
        displayOnly = NO;
        [headerLabel setTitle:@"Click here to switch to display only mode." forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
    }  else{
        displayOnly = YES;
        [headerLabel setTitle:@"Click here to switch to practice session mode." forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
    }
    //may be there's need to make additional call
    [headerView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

This way you hold the same instance of `UIView` and `UIButton` only updating it's title and possibly manually calling to redraw by making `[headerView setNeedsDisplay];` that call.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try debugging your app? Where you are adding headerView in table? you need to change the code like this

```
- (void) switch
{
    if (displayOnly == YES)
    {
        displayOnly = NO;
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = [self headerView];    
    }  
    else
    {
        displayOnly = YES;
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = [self headerView];    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  However, now my header no longer maintains the correct position on the display.  This is where I am adding the headerView in the table:   `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
 return [self headerView];
 }
 
     - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
 return [[self headerView] frame].size.height;
 }`

Comment: you are passing wrong height in - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section { } it should be a static value suppose you want 50 pixels of header then return 50 here and same height should be passed in the frame of UIView you are returning for header View.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried setting the height to a static value, and the headerView display is still jumping around.

Comment: ok send me your code and I will do it the toggle thing and send code back to you by mail. If you don't mind it. My mail id is rahul.vyas.09@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```
if (headerView){
    [headerView removeFromSuperview];
    [headerView release];
}
```

you removing `headerView` from superview, but after creating new `headerView` not adding it to superview.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call table reload data then it will work.